# How do I make Nautilus use preview thumbnails for OpenOffice.org documents?

Tags: nautilus, openoffice.org

In Nautilus by default I have very nice default previews of different file types, for example JPEG, Png, Svg, text or PDF.

Is it possible to make Nautilus show preview thumbnails also of OpenOffice.org documents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated [here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/4367/), you can install [libgsf-bin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libgsf-bin) to enable that feature.

Comment: Confirmed. Above mentioned libgsf-bin, located in Synaptic works fine in Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: didn't work in Ubuntu 12.04 after restart, with an .odt file created by LibreOffice.

Comment: This works fine in ubuntu 13.04 with the patched nautilus